# Find string with optional preceding string followed by an optional whitespace, both with negative lookbehind

Tags: r, regex

I am not sure if the title of this question makes sense. I am looking for a string ("string") which can have an optional preceding string ("a"), which can or cannot be followed by a whitespace. All this should be with a negative lookbehind - this would basically be for the entire following expression.

My regex starts to fail with the negative lookbehind, which makes sense to me, and I wonder how to solve this.

This can be anywhere, and does not have to be at the start.

```r
x <- c("string not false", "this is not a string", "this is a string", "not a string", "not astring", "a string", "astring", "string")

# all the below fail 
grepl("(?<!not\\s{1})a?\\s?string", x, perl = TRUE)
#> [1] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
grepl("(?<!not\\s{1})a\\s?string", x, perl = TRUE)
#> [1]  FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
grepl("(?<!not\\s{1})(\\b|a)\\s?string", x, perl = TRUE)
#> [1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE

# expected output
#> [1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

Comment: no. they can occur anywhere, editing the question now

Comment: `a string`must not be preceded by `not`, correct?

Comment: `(?<!...)`is negative **lookbehind**!

Comment: 1) yes, both should not be preceded by „not“. 2) you’re right. will change that.

Comment: What would be your output for "string not" ?

Comment: @RonakShah This would be TRUE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not avoid lookbehind and go for simple, asking what you want and what you don't want in two separated calls?

```
grepl("a?\\s?string", x) & !grepl("not\\s?a?\\s?string", x)
#[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

---

**Note:**
If you really want only one call to `grepl`, you need to detail a bit more what you want and what you don't want: if you only ask not to have `"not"` but don't specify that `"not "` ("not" followed by a space) isn't ok either, it won't work, you need to put it in the lookbehind. You also need to detail what you want in a lookahead because if you're too flexible in your `regex` (there can be a "a" with or without a space, etc.), `grepl` will still find a match.
The following code (more complicated than 2 `grepl` calls imo) works with your example:

```
grepl("(?<!(not)|(not ))(?=(^string)|(a string)|(astring))", x, perl=TRUE)
#[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

***Data:***
`x <- c("string not false", "this is not a string", "this is a string", "not a string", "not astring", "a string", "astring", "string")`

Answer (score 0):

A `grepl`solution:

```
grepl("^(?!not).*string", x, perl = TRUE)
```

Alternatively, check out:

```
library(stringr)
str_detect(x, "\\bnot\\b", negate = TRUE)
[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

`grepl` does not allow for pattern negation (but `grep`does!)

Data:

```
x <- c("this is a string", "not a string", "not astring", "a string", "astring", "string")
```

Comment: thanks Chris, I have updated my example to be more complex. Both your regex unfortunately fail with that